# AWS corn job i am trying to run my script every one day in a month and that particular day i want to be a weekday (any weekday)

Tags: amazon-web-services, expression

I have already tired with the following arguments.
0 13 */28 * ? *

and getting the following output

Wed, 01 Jun 2022 13:00:00 GMT
Wed, 29 Jun 2022 13:00:00 GMT
Fri, 01 Jul 2022 13:00:00 GMT
Fri, 29 Jul 2022 13:00:00 GMT
Mon, 01 Aug 2022 13:00:00 GMT
Mon, 29 Aug 2022 13:00:00 GMT
Thu, 01 Sep 2022 13:00:00 GMT
Thu, 29 Sep 2022 13:00:00 GMT
Sat, 01 Oct 2022 13:00:00 GMT
Sat, 29 Oct 2022 13:00:00 GMT

Expected output is to avoid Saturday and Sunday

Answer (score 0):

I have tried that I can able to create one day of month.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIC1V.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).